# Enable swanctl plugin of strongswan in yocto

Tags: yocto, strongswan

I have compiled my build of strongswan  on board successfully with deprecated version of strongswan (using stroke and charon). Now trying to configure it with swanctl and enable charon-systemd plugin but didnt get that tried same things as done for simple charon plugin but in vain

````
        --without-lib-prefix "
 
EXTRA_OECONF += "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'systemd', '--with-systemdsystemunitdir=${systemd_unitdir}/system/', '--without-systemdsystemunitdir', d)}"
#include pacakge name here if you want install it 
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "charon curl gmp openssl sqlite3 \
        ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'ldap', 'systemd', 'swanctl', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG[aesni] = "--enable-aesni,--disable-aesni,"
PACKAGECONFIG[charon] = "--enable-charon,--disable-charon,"
PACKAGECONFIG[curl] = "--enable-curl,--disable-curl,curl,"
PACKAGECONFIG[gmp] = "--enable-gmp,--disable-gmp,gmp,"
PACKAGECONFIG[vici] = "--enable-vici,--disable-vici,vici,"
PACKAGECONFIG[ldap] = "--enable-ldap,--disable-ldap,openldap,"
PACKAGECONFIG[mysql] = "--enable-mysql,--disable-mysql,mysql5,"
PACKAGECONFIG[openssl] = "--enable-openssl,--disable-openssl,openssl,"
PACKAGECONFIG[scep] = "--enable-scepclient,--disable-scepclient,"
PACKAGECONFIG[soup] = "--enable-soup,--disable-soup,libsoup-2.4,"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlite3] = "--enable-sqlite,--disable-sqlite,sqlite3,"
PACKAGECONFIG[stroke] = "--enable-stroke,--disable-stroke,"
PACKAGECONFIG[swanctl] = "--enable-swanctl,--disable-swanctl,,libgcc"
#requires swanctl
PACKAGECONFIG[systemd] = "--enable-systemd,--disable-systemd,systemd"
inherit autotools systemd pkgconfig
#
#
#
#
RRECOMMENDS_${PN} = "kernel-module-ipsec"
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/ipsec/lib*${SOLIBS} ${libdir}/ipsec/plugins/*.so"
FILES_${PN}-dbg += "${libdir}/ipsec/.debug ${libdir}/ipsec/plugins/.debug ${libexecdir}/ipsec/.debug"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/ipsec/lib*${SOLIBSDEV} ${libdir}/ipsec/*.la ${libdir}/ipsec/plugins/*.la"
FILES_${PN}-staticdev += "${libdir}/ipsec/*.a ${libdir}/ipsec/plugins/*.a"
#
#
RPROVIDES_${PN} += "${PN}-systemd"
RREPLACES_${PN} += "${PN}-systemd"
RCONFLICTS_${PN} += "${PN}-systemd"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'swanctl', '${BPN}-swanctl.service', '${BPN}.service', d)}"```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " swanctl "
```

Comment: will it enable charon-systemd ? by it self or i should write same line to enable it ?